# Continuity of $f(x) = x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ at $x =0$

Tags: continuity

I want to find whether the function  $$f(x) = x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), \quad x\in \mathbb R^*.$$ 
Here is what I did

Approached this function from left of $x$ axis by assuming $x=0-h$, did the same process by approaching from the right.

Got that Left hand limit equals $-h\sin\left(\frac{-1}{h}\right)$ where $h$ tends to $0$. RHL came out to be $h\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)$. 
    So in short LHL and RHL both seem to have the same expressions. And also the fact $\sin\left(\frac{1}{0}\right)$ would still be between $[-1,1]$ LHL and RHL would tend to zero as $h$ tends to $0$. 
Also value for $f(x)$ at $x= 0$ would also be $0$. Hence $f(x)$ should be continuous at $x=0$.
However, I found out that it is not continuous at $x = 0$. However,
$f(x) = x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ when $x \neq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x = 0$) would be continuous at $x = 0$.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Note that $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ is *not defined* for $x = 0$, so, strictly speaking, the statement *$f$ is continuous at $x = 0$* is meaningless. What you can ask is whether or not $f$ can be extended to a continuous function on the whole of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag That's where I have a doubt, when x equals 0, I know that sin(1/x) would not be defined but I know for a fact that it has to be between [-1,1]. Further, since we have x in multiplication with sin(1/x), I seem to think that 0 * (something between -1 and 1 inclusive) should be 0.

Comment: People often extend this function to be 0 at 0 because the limiting procedure tells us that it locally is pretty damn close to 0. In fact, in some sense, this is what limits are for: patching holes in functions.

Comment: No, $\sin(1/0)$ is not in $[-1,1]$; it is undefined. It is of course true that $\sin(1/h) \in [-1,1]$ for $h \neq 0$, and that is enough to conclude that $\lim_{h \to 0} h\sin(1/h) = 0$.

Comment: Also, note that the edit by @Surb changed the question by modifying the domain of $f$ from ${\Bbb R}$ to ${\Bbb R}^*$. Now, ${\Bbb R}$ cannot be the domain of $f$ (without explicitly saying what the value at $x = 0$ should be), but this seems to be the heart of the problem, not the computation of the limit $\lim_{h \to 0} h\sin(1/h)$ itself.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks for your comment, I understand removable discontinuity, but I want to ask this -  wouldn't it make sense to say that xsin(1/x) should definitely be 0 since sin(1/h),h belongs to R*, even though not defined, would still be between -1 and 1 both inclusive, and when I multiply this undefined yet bound value with 0,answer should be 0?

Comment: @Magdiragdag Thanks, so does it not make sense to say that sin(1/h) for h equals 0 would still be between -1 and 1? Because that's the kind of impression I have in my mind right now.

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself: no, $\sin(1/h)$ for $h = 0$ is not between $-1$ and $1$; it is undefined. Also, note that when computing $\lim_{h \to 0} h\sin(1/h)$ you do *not* evaluate $\sin(1/h)$ at $h = 0$ and then multiply by $0$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag, I think that I have got the idea now. Thanks.